# Reading friendly name of a digital certificate

Tags: java, certificate, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, digital-certificate

I am working on digital certificates using java and I am reading the attributes of the X.509 certificates using the standard getter methods. Below is my code --

```
X509Certificate c = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(fr);
System.out.println("\tCertificate for: " +c.getSubjectDN());
System.out.println("\tCertificate issued by: " +c.getIssuerDN());
System.out.println("\tCertificate SN# " +c.getSerialNumber());
```

I also want to read the friendly name of the certificate. Howver there is no getter something like getFriendlyName. So how can I read the friendly name of a certificate or it cannot be derived programatically?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "friendly name"? [X.509](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509) doesn't define a "friendly name". Are you referring to the Common Name (CN) Distinguished Name, perhaps?

Comment: Yes , I am aware the X.509 doesnt define a friendly name. But there is a friendly name defined in the certificate when you open it in IE.Click on the details tab of the certificate and click edit properties and you will see the friendlyname. Wanted to know how to read that programatically?

Comment: I'm using a Mac - how about posting a screen grab?

Comment: @user496934 whatever you see as a friendly name is NOT stored in the certificate and there's no way to read it from the certificate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Friendly name is not saved in the certificate - it is a feature of the Microsoft Windows certificate store. So it is not cross-platform and that means that there is no standard java API for that.

Comment: I was thinking of that. However, you can edit the friendly name of the certificate and make it different. In this case your approach will not work.

Comment: Than i don't know what are you talking about. Every significant piece of information is signed, so you can't change it. If you've found something that you can change however you want, it should not be used at all and it would be a bad practice.

Comment: Than i don't know what are you talking about. ---This is what I was talking about. Already told it clearly --"But there is a friendly name defined in the certificate when you open it in IE.Click on the details tab of the certificate and click edit properties and you will see the friendlyname. Wanted to know how to read that "\

Comment: Apparently, it is possible to add a "friendly name" attribute (OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.9.20) to an X509 certificate.  Bouncy Castle libraries support setting it.  But the necessary interface, `PKCS12BagAttributeCarrier` is not available in the FIPS implementation (because they're related to PKCS#12, whole other subject).  I'm looking for an alternative API to set it.